# Add shortcut to Windows' "Save As" dialog?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, save-as

I'm running Windows XP SP3, and was wondering if Windows allows adding shortcuts in the "Save As" dialog, in addition to the standard folders (My Recent Documents, Desktop, etc.)?

[image]

Since I happen to save my files in C:\Work, I have to navigate to that folder every time I save a new file, which is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article on PCWorld might help: [Customize File Open and Save Dialog Boxes](http://www.pcworld.com/article/215203/customize_file_open_and_save_dialog_boxes.html). MoishePippik's comment at the end of the article is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys. TweakUI did the trick, although it's limited to 5 locations. If you need more, FileBox eXtender (www.hyperionics.com/files/) has more.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the PICTURE

This is called "Places" the simplest way to edit places is to aquire the program TweakUI from a legitimate source , like microsoft itself. It is a "Power Toy" .
I cant get to it now in W7, but you should be able to find the places in there quick enough. it is in "Common Dialogs" "Places Bar"

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp  (halfway down the page)

TweakUI does not actually have to be installed , it will potentially run as a single executable, making it very simple, although it comes in a proper installation package, making it a bigger pain than it has to be . :-)

TweakUi is so quick to edit some things, I could hop in and change it to directories I was using during a session.

Places can easily be changed in the registry also, if you want to know the locations just ask.

TweakUI does not function properly under windows 7

Answer (score 1):

You can also download DirectFolders from the makers of Teracopy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better alternative

[How to Customize Default Places Bar in Windows Common Open File Dialog Boxes](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/85487-common-file-dialog-box-customize-places-bar.html)

Comment: Could you put the relevant information in your answer? Links to other websites aren't always so permanent, and answers that have the info right there are generally preferable to just links.

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder you want to save as a shortcut, then move your mouse into the save as box (on the left), right click, the folder will appear for you to add

Comment: You realize this makes no sense, right?